# How to analyze this bandstop filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

This is a Sallen-Key second order notch filter(bandstop filter) :
[image]

This filter attenuates the frequency at \$f_0=\frac{1}{2\pi RC}\$. But I don't get how. How should I analyze this kind of circuit?

What I only understand:

- At very low frequencies the signal reaches the noninverting input due to caps being open
- At very high frequencies the signal still reaches the noninverting input due to caps being shorted.
- Lastly, the R/2 acts as positive feedback

Do analyzation of this circuit needs knowledge of transfer function? (since I haven't taken that subject, yet)

Comment: The HPF and the LPF have a slight gap where frequencies are blocked. You can work out the math independently and see that Fo is the same. Requires precision (0.1%) resistors and matched capacitors to work well.

Comment: Start by learning how to analyse the standard passive notch filter of a very similar design but without the op-amp. Don't run before you learn to walk. Star-Delta transforms will help you solve the math. R/2 isn't positive feedback. It's feedback but not positive.

Comment: Understood, I thought first it will need knowledge of transfer function, but it seems I won't need that, right?

Comment: If you are familiar with the representation of impedance (to ac signals) of a capacitor as \$ \frac{1}{j\omega C} \$ or \$ \frac{1}{sC} \$, and also familiar with nodal (or mesh) analysis using the above, you don't need any extra knowledge in the area of transfer functions to work out \$v_o / v_i\$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following [opamp-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUMlbC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5\\
\\
0=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{I}_\text{o}=\text{I}_6+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_8}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_8}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{I}_\text{o}=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_6}+\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_8}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_3=\text{V}_4:=\text{V}_x$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
0=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_7}=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_8}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{I}_\text{o}=\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_6}+\frac{\text{V}_5-\text{V}_x}{\text{R}_8}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{V}_5}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\tag5$$

```
((R1 R4 R5 + R2 R3 R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) (R7 + 
     R8))/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
   R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8)
```

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=V3 = Vx;
V4 = Vx;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ii == I1 + I2, I4 == I1 + I6, I2 == I3 + I5, 0 == I3 + I4, 
   I7 == I8, Ii + Io == I6 + I8, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (Vi - V2)/R2, I3 == (V2 - V3)/R3, I4 == (V1 - V3)/R4, 
   I5 == V2/R5, I6 == (V5 - V1)/R6, I7 == V4/R7, 
   I8 == (V5 - V4)/R8}, {V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, Ii, Io, I1, I2, I3, I4, 
   I5, I6, I7, I8}]]

Out[1]={{V1 -> (((R1 R4 R5 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R5 R6 + 
           R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6) R7 + 
        R1 R4 R5 R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
      R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  V2 -> (R5 (R1 R4 R7 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R6 R7 - 
        R1 R3 R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
      R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  Vx -> ((R1 R4 R5 + 
        R2 R3 R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) R7 Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  V5 -> ((R1 R4 R5 + R2 R3 R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) (R7 + 
        R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
      R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  Ii -> ((((R1 + R2) R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R6) R7 - ((R1 + 
              R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R8) Vi)/(((R3 + 
            R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
      R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  Io -> ((R1 (R4 + R6) (R5 - R7) + 
        R1 (R3 + 2 R5) R8 + (R3 + R4) (R5 R6 - R6 R7 + 2 R5 R8) + 
        R2 (R6 (R3 + R5 - R7) - 2 R4 R7 + 
           2 (R3 + R5) R8)) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I1 -> ((-R2 (R4 + R6) R7 + 
        R2 R3 R8 + (R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R8) Vi)/(-(R1 R4 (R2 + R5) + 
          R2 (R1 + R3 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) R7 + 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I2 -> ((R1 R4 R7 + (R1 + R3 + R4) R6 R7 - 
        R1 (R3 + R5) R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I3 -> -(((R2 R6 R7 + 
          R1 R5 R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
        R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8)), 
  I4 -> ((R2 R6 R7 + 
        R1 R5 R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
      R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I5 -> ((R1 R4 R7 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R6 R7 - 
        R1 R3 R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
      R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I6 -> ((-R2 R4 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R8 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R8) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I7 -> ((R1 R4 R5 + 
        R2 R3 R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8), 
  I8 -> ((R1 R4 R5 + 
        R2 R3 R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) Vi)/(((R3 + R4) R5 + 
         R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - 
      R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8)}}
```

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_5=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_3}\tag8$$

Now, when we look at your circuit, we can make a few more simplifications:

- $$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag9$$
- $$\text{R}_5=\frac{1}{2\text{sC}}\tag{10}$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\text{R}_3=\text{R}\tag{11}$$
- $$\text{R}_6=\frac{\text{R}}{2}\tag{12}$$

So, we can rewrite the transfer function as:

$$\mathcal{h}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\left(\text{R}_7+\text{R}_8\right)\left(1+\left(\text{CRs}\right)^2\right)}{\text{R}_7\left(1+\text{sCR}\right)^2-2\text{CR}\text{R}_8\text{s}}\tag{13}$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[2]:=R1 = 1/(s*c);
R4 = 1/(s*c);
R5 = 1/(2*s*c);
R2 = R;
R3 = R;
R6 = R/2;
FullSimplify[((R1 R4 R5 + R2 R3 R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6) (R7 + 
      R8))/(((R3 + R4) R5 + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)) R6 R7 + 
    R1 (R2 + R5) (R4 + R6) R7 - R1 (R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R5)) R8)]

Out[2]=((R7 + R8) (1 + c^2 R^2 s^2))/(-2 c R R8 s + R7 (1 + c R s)^2)
```

Comment: Nice job and well written!

Comment: @Derik Thank you so so much!